# Kinect not getting power from Irobot create base. is it openni problem?

Tags: kinect, openni, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

now i use turtlebot(create). but kinect don't get power from Irobot create base.
usb version is 2.0, and ubuntu 12.04 , ROS fuerte.
Kinect is a red status light.
is this problem openni problem?? if It is, please let me know what to do

**If I operate openni.launch, the result is**
"[ INFO] [1375071903.030941613]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected"

**and dashboard's result is**

Node: /openni_driver
Time: 1375071912.050908274
Severity: Info
Location: /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-openni-camera-1.8.6/debian/ros-fuerte-openni-camera/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/src/nodelets/driver.cpp:DriverNodelet::setupDevice:218
Published Topics: /rosout

No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected

what is the problem?? if you know that, please let me know.

thank you ^^

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68197/kinect-not-getting-power-from-irobot-create-base.-is-it-openni-problem??/) by [FourTrees](https://answers.ros.org/users/5449/fourtrees/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2013-07-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-25**:
I am having problem while connecting the kinect power using DB25 connector of Irobot create base. The connector circuit is designed by clearpath robotics to provide 12V DC power to kinect by taking power from pin 10 and 14 of DB25 connector of irobot create base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am facing the same problem that kinect not getting power from Irobot create base....
**However I am very much sure that it is not an openni problem.**

I read to a tutorial by Prof. Jason O'Kane he says that :
**For the Kinect sensor to operate correctly, it must draw power from the Create’s battery. (The 5V available from the USB connection to the netbook is not sufﬁcient; the Kinect needs at least 8V. Note that seeing blinking lights in the Kinect is, in my experience, not enough to know for sure that the Kinect is receiving the power it needs.)
Your Turtlebot has a cable connecting the Kinect to the Create for this purpose, but by default that power supply is disabled. To enable it .........**

```
**rosrun create_node kinect_breaker_enabler.py**
```

I tried it but this was not working. The create base is connected to ttyACM0 port as the serial to USB connector definition.
Then I checked the power supply of pin 10-11-12 of DB25 connector and found that the above command working well and I robot create giving power supply of 14V DC. So it is problem of 12V DC regulator circuit board. Which I will replace soon.

---

Originally posted by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) with karma: 205 on 2013-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-28**:
If you get to resolve the problem then please do let me too by posting the solution. Thanking you.

**Comment by [FourTrees](https://answers.ros.org/users/5449/fourtrees/) on 2013-07-28**:
sure, I operated 'rosrun create_node kinect_breaker_enabler.py'. but I don't solve it.
if I know that, I will notice you

**Comment by [FourTrees](https://answers.ros.org/users/5449/fourtrees/) on 2013-07-29**:
I sended mail about my question.

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-29**:
to whom you sent the e-mail?

**Comment by [FourTrees](https://answers.ros.org/users/5449/fourtrees/) on 2013-07-29**:
turtlebot company -> iheartenginerring

I attached contents below

**Comment by [FourTrees](https://answers.ros.org/users/5449/fourtrees/) on 2013-07-30**:
I found this solution. My power cable(from create base to kinect) is wrong.
+12v cable and ground cable connected incorrectly.
Could you look at this part again????

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-30**:
is it working now?
Please e-mail me the detail about the connector n circuit you are using and steps to run. mailID- gyanendra2004@gmail.com

**Comment by [FourTrees](https://answers.ros.org/users/5449/fourtrees/) on 2013-08-02**:
I sended e-mail to you ^^

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-08-02**:
When you sent, its not yet received.